# Why am I unable to add lines from a text file to an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have the following code below. If I comment out the `stringList.add(row);` I can get it to print the lines of the document (5 lines of text with spaces). If I don't comment it out, I get one line printed and the null. I have looked up everything I could online but I am not understanding why this is happening!

```
package examples.files;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class ReadFileUsingScanner {
    static ArrayList<String> stringList = null;
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = null;

        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("customers.txt"));

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String row = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(row);
                stringList.add(row);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (scanner != null) {
                try {
                    scanner.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You don't have to solve the code but I want to understand the fundamentals as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, you should add the stacktrace to your questions. It isn't "printing the null", it is throwing an exception

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I will add that - which is probably why I wasn't catching such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your arrayList is not initialized. Change to

```
static ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Oh my god, thanks. That's embarrassing!

Answer (score 0):

The bug is NPE(NullPointException).

And the next time you get a bug,you may not need to ask a question on StackOverFlow.Try Debugger Function of the IDE line by line.You will get the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.